# is it possible simple_captcha with json in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Is it possible to use simple_captcha2 with json in Rails?
I need to send the image to the client (angularjs), show it, read the answer and send it to server (Rails) throught json to verify it.

I know when

> <%= show_simple_captcha %>

In database (example):

```
select * from simple_captcha_data 
id:
key: "94f701cc098d8f70a84e081a03a19994bb3c4b62";
value: "LQQNOK";
created_at: "2016-07-26 16:52:44.389791";
updated_at: "2016-07-26 16:52:44.389791"
```

and the image is:

```
http://.../simple_captcha?code=94f701cc098d8f70a84e081a03a19994bb3c4b62&time=1469551964
```

key + time, time when key is created

If, for example, I use for :Processing by PasswordsController#create as HTML

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
    "user"=>{"email"=>"...@..."}, 
    "captcha"=>"LQQNOK", 
    "captcha_key"=>"94f701cc098d8f70a84e081a03a19994bb3c4b62", 
    "commit"=>"..."}
```

**so I only need to know how can I create a new record in simple_captcha_data and to know its time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the next code in your controller:

`include SimpleCaptcha::ViewHelper`

```
def name_of_function(options = {})
    key = simple_captcha_key(options[:object])
      if options[:multiple] === false
        # It's not the first captcha, we only need to return the key
        key
      else
        # It's the first captcha in the page, we generate a new key
        set_simple_captcha_data(key, options)
      end
end
```

Upon receipt of the key, **key_captcha**,  you show in your app image by, example:

```
<div class='simple_captcha'>
  <div class='simple_captcha_image'>
    <img src="{{protocolo}}://{{serverIp}}/simple_captcha?code={{key_captcha}}" alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="120">
  </div>
  <div class='simple_captcha_field'>
    <input id="captcha_text" type="text" value='' placeholder="Introduzca el texto">
  </div>
</div>
```

That's all, now you can send "captcha" and "captcha_key" in the request